# gradle prefix exclude dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, transitive-dependency

When developing Hadoop applications very quickly many sub-modules of the main Hadoop project are required.
In order to force a specific version, I as the author of my own Hadoop job would love to change the version of Hadoop for transitive libraries.

I.e. for all `hadoop-*` dependencies and transitive dependencies I want to set them to a version `foo.bar.baz`

How can I achieve this with Gradle without the need to manually specify each module?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write a custom dependency resolution rule. For example:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.hadoop") {
            useVersion("3.2.1")
            because("some description why this version is needed.")
        }
    }
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html

An alternative to the above is to create/publish you're own custom [platform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) or "BOM".

Comment: Would it also be possible to put this into a different scope and apply this rule only to a specific dependency (and whatever it is pulling in transitively)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle 6+, I would strongly recommend looking into the dedicated chapter on [dependency alignment](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_version_alignment.html#header) and in particular the part about using [virtual platforms](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_version_alignment.html#sec:virtual_platform). This combined with a [strict version constraint](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version) should give you the result you need.

If you need to support a wider range of Gradle versions, the answer from Francisco Mateo with a resolution rule is a valid approach.

Comment: No gradle 6.2 - if needed also 6.3 is fine.

Comment: However, for `strict` to work, I need to know the exact clashing dependency and I also need to enumerate all sub-modules i.e. in case of hadoop this is a large number.